# InvocationTargetException when trying to switch scene [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I try switching my scene, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Here is the method when I switch the scene:

```
public void changeScene(String sceneID) throws Exception{

    Parent newScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(sceneID));
    Scene scene;
    scene = new Scene(newScene, 800, 600);

    window.setScene(scene);

    window.show();
}
```

Comment: I am going to guess that your `sceneID` does not points to your `fxml's` current location.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent newScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sceneID.fxml"));
```

//If this URL is wrong or any problem in the fxml at this URL then you get Invocation exception or Nullpointer exception etc

```
Scene scene;
scene = new Scene(newScene, 800, 600);

window.setScene(scene);
window.show();
```

try this and if you still have trouble then post your FXML here.